# Bootstrap - cant set main-container height to 100%

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I can figure out how to set height of my .main-container height to 100%.

It looks like this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKZUe.png)
I cant set my sidebar to 100%, when i do

```
.main-container {
    height: 94vh;
}
```

the height is too high.

There is some of my code, Im using bootstrap 5:
Navbar:

```
<nav class="navbar fixed-top custom-navbar">
```

to position my sidebar nad main page im using:

```
<div class="main-container d-flex">
    <div id="side_nav">...</div>
    <div class="content">...</div>
</div>
```

css

```
body {
    background: #f5f7fa;
    padding-top: 3.5rem;
}
.content {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

#side_nav {
    background: #ffffff;
    min-width: 300px;
    max-width: 300px;
    position: relative;
    border-right: 1px solid #cbd0dd;
}
```

Comment: 100% of what? The viewport or fill the remaining height below the navbar? What is the purpose of 94vh? Is the navbar 6vh?

Comment: To fill the remaining height below the navbar, 94vh beacuse it is only working for me. I also want make my sidebar static, beacuse now when im scrolling items inside of navbar going down as well.

Comment: What do you want to happen with scrolling the content?

Comment: I want scrolling only main page on the right. On the sidebar i want have it to be static like navbar and sidebar will have own scroll bar if there is to much items

Comment: Great, can you please clarify the question to explain this? Also what about the content scrolling if it's taller than the sidebar?

Comment: "content" div should have his own scroll bar i guess

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to: [Bootstrap Navbar and content fill height flexbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49191957) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51729634/make-main-container-use-100-of-height?noredirect=1&lq=1) since **Bootstrap 5** flexbox works the same way.

"100%" and "fill remaining height" are 2 different things. I think what you're asking for is 100% height layout with Navbar where the main-container doesn't exceed the viewport height, and fills the remaining space.

```
body {
    background: #f5f7fa;
    padding-top: 3.5rem;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.content {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

#side_nav {
    background: #ffffff;
    min-width: 300px;
    max-width: 300px;
    position: relative;
    border-right: 1px solid #cbd0dd;
}

<nav class="navbar fixed-top custom-navbar"> Nav </nav>
<div class="main-container d-flex bg-light flex-grow-1 overflow-auto">
    <div id="side_nav" class="overflow-auto">
        <h1>sidebar</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="content overflow-auto">
        <h1>content</h1>
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

https://codeply.com/p/8P05IqFLFY